# Rails 5 js.erb shows error ActionView::Template::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to display error messages inside my Rails 5 modal. To do so I created below code:

```
#notes_controller.rb

  def create
    @note = Note.new(note_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @note.save
        format.html { redirect_to history_registrant_path(@registrant) }
      else
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

#views form

    <%= form_for @note, :url => registrant_notes_path(@registrant), remote: true do |f| %>
      <div class="text-note">
        <%= f.label :body, 'Add note' %>
        <%= f.text_area :body, maxlength: 1000, id: "review_text" %>
        <%= show_errors(@note, :body) %>
    
        <div class="counter-text">
          <span id="counter" data-maximum-length="1000"><%= 1000 %></span> chars left / 1000 character max
        </div>
        <%= f.hidden_field :administrator_id, value: current_login.id %>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

which should be handled by:

```
#views/notes/create.js.erb

    $("#error").html("<%= show_errors(@note, :body) %>");
```

application_helper

```
  def show_errors(object, field_name)
    return unless object.errors.key?(field_name)
    tag.p(class: 'error') do
      object.errors.messages[field_name].join(', ')
    end
  end
```

After submitting empty form the error `no blank` should be displayed inside the modal (below form). Instead I'm getting an error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..4)):
    1: $("#error").html("<%= show_errors(@note, :body) %>");

app/helpers/application_helper.rb:35:in `show_errors'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, replace your code with

```
def create
  @note = Note.new(note_params)

  flash[:notice] = "Note saved successfully." if @note.save
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

and in create.js.erb

```
<% if @note.errors.present?  %>
  $("#error").html("<%= show_errors(@note)&.html_safe %>");
<% else %>
  window.location.reload();
<% end %>
```

in application_helper.rb

```
def show_errors(resource_obj)
  return unless resource_obj.errors.any?

  error_msg = '<div id="error_explanation" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button><ul>'
  resource_obj.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
    error_msg += "<li>#{msg}</li>"
  end
  error_msg += '</ul></div>'
  error_msg
end
```

Comment: it produces pretty similar error: `ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..4)):
    1: <% if @note.errors.present?  %>
    2:   $("#error").html("<%= show_errors(@note, :body) %>");
    3: <% else %>
    4:   window.location.reload();
    5: <% end %> app/helpers/application_helper.rb:35:in show_errors`

Comment: I made edit to my answer.

Comment: Now I cannot even open modal - this error shows up: `ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)):
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:31:in show_errors
app/views/notes/_form.html.erb:5:in block in app_views_notes__form_html_erb__1741490392934500157_70325303706600`